# $\forall\delta, \sigma \in F$ where $\delta \land \sigma$ are contrad., $\exists\theta$ so that $\delta\land\neg\theta$ & $\sigma\land\theta$ contrad.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I'm in my first logic class ever and I'm trying to wrap my head around this obscure question...

Show that for all pairs $\delta, \sigma \in F$, where $\delta, \sigma$ contradict themselves there exists a $\theta \in F$ with $\tau(\theta) \subseteq \tau(\delta) \cap \tau(\sigma)$, so that $(\delta\land\neg\theta)$ contradict themselves as well as $(\sigma\land\theta)$ contradict themselves,

where $F$ are all propositional logic formulas, and $\tau(X)$ is the set of all actual propositional variables in X.

So the only thing I know is here that contradicting in this case means that $\delta \land \sigma$ is unsatisfiable. But I really don't know how to continue. I've thought about maybe constructing $\theta$ by formulas of $\delta[\overline{\alpha}/\overline{\beta}]$ (meaning that every occurence of  $\alpha_{i}$ is replaced with $\beta_{i}$) where $\overline{\alpha}:=\tau(\delta)\setminus \tau(\sigma)$ with $\overline{\beta} \in \{0,1\}^{|\overline{\alpha}|}$ as a possible allocation for $\overline{\alpha}$.

Could anyone help me on this? Would really appreciate it!! :)

Comment: See [Craig Interpolation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Craig_interpolation)

Comment: I'm afraid I can't use a Theorem that hasn't been proved in our lecture :(

Comment: In the provided link there is the proof.

Comment: Sorry, this is my very first Logic homework so I don't really understand how the theorem could help me...

Comment: First hw in first logic course?!?  That's hardcore!

Comment: Prof just wants to torture us :'(

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*

Consider that to say that $\{ δ,σ \}$ is *unsatisfiable* means that $δ,σ \vDash \bot$, from which:

> $δ \vDash \lnot σ$.

Thus, to find $θ$ such that $(δ∧¬θ)$ and $(σ∧θ)$ are unsatisfiable, amounts to finding $θ$ such that: $(δ∧¬θ) \vDash \bot$ and $(σ∧θ) \vDash \bot$ respectively, i.e. $\vDash δ 
 \to θ$ and $\vDash θ  \to \lnot σ$.

Now we can apply the construction of [Craig's interpolation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Craig_interpolation#Proof_of_Craig%27s_interpolation_theorem).

Comment: hmmm, so the answer to the question is basically almost the proof in Wikipedia?!